# Apache 2 types SSl using VirtualHosts

Tags: apache, ssl, openssl, virtualhost, httpd.conf

I have 2 different applications.

1) **tools.helpme.com** Require Client Certificates from users!

```
SSLCACertificateFile /usr/local/etc/apache22/certs/cacert.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /usr/local/etc/apache22/certs/server.key
SSLCertificateFile /usr/local/etc/apache22/certs/server.crt
SSLCertificateChainFile /usr/local/etc/apache22/certs/server.crt
SSLVerifyClient require
```

2) **apps.helpme.com** Requires basic SSL from the Server only!

```
SSLCACertificateFile /usr/local/etc/apache22/certs/cacert.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /usr/local/etc/apache22/certs/server.key
SSLCertificateFile /usr/local/etc/apache22/certs/server.crt
SSLCertificateChainFile /usr/local/etc/apache22/certs/server.crt
SSLVerifyClient none
```

I have each of them working independently of the other - and it is perfect.

However, I cannot get both of them running together, they are on different VirtualHosts - Name based hosting.

If I try run both of them together, it seems (2) takes preference and works, but (1) gets a GATEWAY_TIMEOUT!
The error log for that virtaul host says: Re-negotiation handshake failed: Not accepted by client!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the sites on two different IP addresses, as the SSL handshake occurs before sending the HOST http header. You can run on separate port numbers though with the same IP, but that doesn't really help for two different web services?

Comment: Thanks for this. 
Having investigated more, it seems quite common, and I could use SNI for this - if openssl, apache and the browser support it (NOT SO IN MY CASE).
Looks like I will have to set up a seperate server, os use the same SSL for both applications.